# How to grep a bz2 file that is further under a zip folder

Tags: grep, zip

How to grep a bz2 file that is further under a zip folder - Ex: I have a work.zip folder inside which i got a couple of XXX.bz2 files which have a pattern i am searching for. I want to avoid unzipping the parent folder, is there a way?

Comment: If you are searching for _names_, `zip -sf work.zip` will give you that, but if you want to search for _contents_, you're going to have to unzip the archive

Comment: `unzip -p archive.zip | bzgrep 'regex'`?

Answer (score 0):

Try [ugrep](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) with options `-z` and `--zmax=2` to search 2 dearchiving/decompression levels deep, such as grepping bz2 files in a zip file.